# Getting Object #<Object> has no method 'map' in Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a App.js like this,

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Model = Ember.Object.extend({

});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect : function() {
        this.transitionTo('users');
    }
});

App.UsersController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

        filteredContent : function() {
            var searchText = this.get('searchText'), regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');

            return this.get('model').filter(function(item) {
                return regex.test(item.name);
            });
        }.property('searchText', 'model')

});

App.User = App.Model.extend({
    id : null,
    firstname : null,
    email : null
});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return App.User.findAll();
    }
});

App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(params) {
      //var everyone = this.controllerFor('users');
      return App.User.findBy('id', params.user_id);
    }
});


App.User.reopenClass({
    findAll : function() {
        return $.getJSON("http://pioneerdev.us/users/index", function(data) {
            return data.map(function(row) {
                return App.User.create(row);
            });
        });
    }
});


App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('users', function() {
        this.resource('user',{path: '/:user_id'});
    });
});
```

HTML,

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">

            {{input type="text" value=searchText}}

            {{#each item in filteredContent }}
            <tr><td>
              {{#link-to 'user' item}} <p>{{item.firstname}}</p>{{/link-to}}
            </td></tr>
            {{/each}}

            {{outlet}}
        </script>


     <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user">
    <h2>
        {{email}}
   </h2>

    </script>
```

and I am getting a error like this on Chrome,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'map'
```

and Firefox gives me, `TypeError: data.map is not a function`

Here's the Sample of JSON,

```
{"users":[{"id":"1","firstname":"Marilyn","lastname":"Hughes","address":"4 Johnson Alley","state":"Utah","country":"US","email":"lfreeman@skyvu.info","phone":"6471228888","experience":"5","designation":"Writer"},{"id":"2","firstname":"John","lastname":"Porter","address":"86228 Commercial Court","state":"Pennsylvania","country":"US","email":"jporter@zoomdog.net","phone":"9018889877","experience":"3","designation":"Design"},{"id":"3","firstname":"Frances","lastname":"Johnson","address":"489 Summit Lane","state":"Minnesota","country":"US","email":"fjohnson@teklist.net","phone":null,"experience":"2","designation":"Script"}]}
```

What might be the issue? I am pretty sure it's an issue with .getJSON.

Should I use `data.users.map` instead of `data.map`? But when I use this, I get error on this line,

`return this.get('model').filter(function(item) {`

saying,

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'filter'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to use `data.users.map`, because you are expectiong an array of elements, in the model property from controller.

The `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'filter'` error is because,  `this.get('model')` have the `data` no `data.users`. So `Object` class don't have a method called filter, just `Array`. That data is returned from `$.getJSON().then()` method that resolve with the data:

```
$.getJSON().then(function(data) {
  // something like this is made by ember
  // controller.set('model', data);
});
```

And you need data.users as ember objects.

So I update your code to the following:

```
App.User.reopenClass({
    findAll : function() {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $.getJSON("http://pioneerdev.us/users/index", function(data) {
                var result = data.users.map(function(row) {
                    return App.User.create(row);
                });
                // here we resolve the array with ember objects
                // so you will have this.get('model') filled with array of users
                resolve(result);
            }).fail(reject);
        });
    }
});
```

It is a good idea to use the `RSVP.Promise` because this is the promises api used by ember.

This is the fiddle showing this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/HtJEh/

Comment: Okay, Now I have a weird problem, the data is not displayed on HTML side :/

Comment: Hmm strange. Does the fiddle work for you? I dont understand your problem, can you describe more details?

Comment: My bad, it was an error on HTML side. :) Thanks for the help! :D